# How to align the rectangle to be end at the beginning of another in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to achieve the following effect. After creating the first bar,

```
\path node[] (a) at (0,0) {Overlapped days} node (r) [rectangle,right=of a,fill=green!32,minimum width=6cm,minimum height=0.6cm]{} ;
```

I am puzzled at how to create the second rectangle (with the label `day_0`) so that its starting and ending positions can be aligned. I don't want to hardcode a bunch of numbers because the text `Overlapped days` can be changing, and ideally I'd like to have the second rectangle positioned automatically.

Can you please help? Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (a) {Overlapped days};
\node[rectangle, right=of a, fill=green!32, minimum width=6cm, minimum height=0.6cm] (r) {};
\draw[dashed] (r.west) ++(0,1) -- +(0,-4);
\draw[dashed] (r.east) ++(0,1) -- +(0,-4);
\node[rectangle, anchor=north east, fill=gray, minimum width=6cm, minimum height=0.6cm]  (r2) at ([yshift=-1.5cm] r.south west)  {};
\node[below] at (r.south west) {start};
\node[below] at (r.south east) {end};
\node[above] at (r2.north west) {day\_0};
\node[above] at (r2.north east) {start};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Two colored rectangles with text and lines]

Comment: upvoted, this is nice! didn't realize the way to use anchor. If I want to draw another rectangle which is from the midpoint of `r2` to the midpoint of `r` with a `yshift` of -1.5cm, how can I do that? Here, we have two anchors?

Comment: You are on you your way to create a Gantt chart. You should look into the `pgfgantt` package. A node adjust its size to its content or if empty then `minimum width` , so to do that you would instead fill a rectangle like this: `\fill[pink] ([yshift=-1.5cm]r2) rectangle ([yshift=-1.5cm+0.6cm]r2-|r);`